# iptables append fails when using state module

Tags: linux-kernel, iptables, embedded

I'm trying to set up iptables on a custom linux kernel. I have ran into a little issue where state module seems to be load but i receive an error when i attempt to set a state. Iptables help menu options seems to suggest that the state module is configured. I have turned on about the defconfs i believe are needed but it seems I am still missing something. I have a included the error message i receive from iptables below, as well as the script im using to setup iptables. The two things i have noticed will researching this is that i dont have a pre/post routing chain available.

**command that fails**

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

**iptable rules**

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ftp
   60  6061 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
 3140  175K ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:1883
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8883
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:5678
 182K   41M ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
  318 87450 DROP       all  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 437 packets, 97449 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 185K   41M ACCEPT     all  --  any    lo      anywhere             anywhere
```

**script for configuring iptalbes**

```
iptables -F


iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 37 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1883 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8883 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5678 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j DROP

iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

ip6tables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 37 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1883 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8883 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5678 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT

ip6tables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

ip6tables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

ip6tables -P INPUT DROP
ip6tables -P FORWARD DROP
ip6tables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

**kernel defconfig**

```
CONFIG_NETFILTER=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_CONNTRACK=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_FTP=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_IRC=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_IPTABLES=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_FILTER=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_NAT=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_STATE=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_LOG=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_LIMIT=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_MASQUERADE=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_REDIRECT=y
CONFIG_NF_TABLES=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XTABLES=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_INGRESS=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_MARK=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_PROCFS=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_TIMEOUT=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_TIMESTAMP=y
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which config option provides the `state` module but you should use the `conntrack` module and `--ctstate` anyway.

Comment: thanks for your rely. so the command should be something like "iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack -ctstate RELATED -j DROP"?

Answer (score 0):

adding the following to my config enabled ipv6, iptables and allow the state to work properly. I went for the shotgun approach because i dont want to speed to much time on this one setting.

```
CONFIG_PACKET_DIAG=y
CONFIG_UNIX=y
CONFIG_UNIX_DIAG=y
CONFIG_XFRM=y
CONFIG_XFRM_ALGO=y
CONFIG_XFRM_USER=y
# CONFIG_XFRM_SUB_POLICY is not set
# CONFIG_XFRM_MIGRATE is not set
CONFIG_XFRM_STATISTICS=y
CONFIG_XFRM_IPCOMP=y
CONFIG_NET_KEY=y
# CONFIG_NET_KEY_MIGRATE is not set
CONFIG_INET=y
CONFIG_IP_MULTICAST=y
CONFIG_IP_ADVANCED_ROUTER=y
CONFIG_IP_FIB_TRIE_STATS=y
CONFIG_IP_MULTIPLE_TABLES=y
CONFIG_IP_ROUTE_MULTIPATH=y
CONFIG_IP_ROUTE_VERBOSE=y
CONFIG_IP_ROUTE_CLASSID=y
# CONFIG_IP_PNP is not set
CONFIG_NET_IPIP=y
CONFIG_NET_IPGRE_DEMUX=y
CONFIG_NET_IP_TUNNEL=y
CONFIG_NET_IPGRE=y
CONFIG_NET_IPGRE_BROADCAST=y
CONFIG_IP_MROUTE=y
# CONFIG_IP_MROUTE_MULTIPLE_TABLES is not set
CONFIG_IP_PIMSM_V1=y
CONFIG_IP_PIMSM_V2=y
CONFIG_SYN_COOKIES=y
CONFIG_NET_IPVTI=y
CONFIG_NET_UDP_TUNNEL=y
CONFIG_NET_FOU=y
CONFIG_NET_FOU_IP_TUNNELS=y
CONFIG_INET_AH=y
CONFIG_INET_ESP=y
CONFIG_INET_IPCOMP=y
CONFIG_INET_XFRM_TUNNEL=y
CONFIG_INET_TUNNEL=y
CONFIG_INET_XFRM_MODE_TRANSPORT=y
CONFIG_INET_XFRM_MODE_TUNNEL=y
CONFIG_INET_XFRM_MODE_BEET=y
CONFIG_INET_DIAG=y
CONFIG_INET_TCP_DIAG=y
CONFIG_INET_UDP_DIAG=y
CONFIG_INET_DIAG_DESTROY=y
CONFIG_TCP_CONG_ADVANCED=y
CONFIG_TCP_CONG_BIC=y
CONFIG_TCP_CONG_CUBIC=y
CONFIG_TCP_CONG_WESTWOOD=y
CONFIG_TCP_CONG_HTCP=y
CONFIG_TCP_CONG_HSTCP=y
CONFIG_TCP_CONG_HYBLA=y
CONFIG_TCP_CONG_VEGAS=y
CONFIG_TCP_CONG_NV=y
CONFIG_TCP_CONG_SCALABLE=y
CONFIG_TCP_CONG_LP=y
CONFIG_TCP_CONG_VENO=y
CONFIG_TCP_CONG_YEAH=y
CONFIG_TCP_CONG_ILLINOIS=y
CONFIG_TCP_CONG_DCTCP=y
CONFIG_TCP_CONG_CDG=y
CONFIG_TCP_CONG_BBR=y
CONFIG_DEFAULT_CUBIC=y
# CONFIG_DEFAULT_RENO is not se
CONFIG_DEFAULT_TCP_CONG="cubic"
CONFIG_TCP_MD5SIG=y
CONFIG_IPV6=y
CONFIG_IPV6_ROUTER_PREF=y
CONFIG_IPV6_ROUTE_INFO=y
CONFIG_INET6_AH=y
CONFIG_INET6_ESP=y
CONFIG_INET6_IPCOMP=y
CONFIG_IPV6_MIP6=y
CONFIG_IPV6_ILA=y
CONFIG_INET6_XFRM_TUNNEL=y
CONFIG_INET6_TUNNEL=y
CONFIG_INET6_XFRM_MODE_TRANSPORT=y
CONFIG_INET6_XFRM_MODE_TUNNEL=y
CONFIG_INET6_XFRM_MODE_BEET=y
CONFIG_INET6_XFRM_MODE_ROUTEOPTIMIZATION=y
CONFIG_IPV6_VTI=y
CONFIG_IPV6_SIT=y
CONFIG_IPV6_SIT_6RD=y
CONFIG_IPV6_NDISC_NODETYPE=y
CONFIG_IPV6_TUNNEL=y
CONFIG_IPV6_GRE=y
CONFIG_IPV6_FOU=y
CONFIG_IPV6_FOU_TUNNEL=y
CONFIG_IPV6_MULTIPLE_TABLES=y
CONFIG_IPV6_SUBTREES=y
CONFIG_IPV6_MROUTE=y
CONFIG_IPV6_MROUTE_MULTIPLE_TABLES=y
CONFIG_IPV6_PIMSM_V2=y
CONFIG_NETLABEL=y
CONFIG_NETWORK_SECMARK=y
CONFIG_NET_PTP_CLASSIFY=y
CONFIG_NETWORK_PHY_TIMESTAMPING=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER=y
# CONFIG_NETFILTER_DEBUG is not set
CONFIG_NETFILTER_ADVANCED=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_NETFILTER=y

#
# Core Netfilter Configuration
#
CONFIG_NETFILTER_INGRESS=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK_ACCT=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK_QUEUE=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK_LOG=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK=y
CONFIG_NF_LOG_COMMON=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_MARK=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_SECMARK=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_ZONES=y
# CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_PROCFS is not set
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_EVENTS=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_TIMEOUT=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_TIMESTAMP=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_LABELS=y
CONFIG_NF_CT_PROTO_DCCP=y
CONFIG_NF_CT_PROTO_GRE=y
CONFIG_NF_CT_PROTO_SCTP=y
CONFIG_NF_CT_PROTO_UDPLITE=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_AMANDA=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_FTP=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_H323=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_IRC=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_BROADCAST=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_NETBIOS_NS=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_SNMP=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_PPTP=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_SANE=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_SIP=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_TFTP=y
CONFIG_NF_CT_NETLINK=y
CONFIG_NF_CT_NETLINK_TIMEOUT=y
CONFIG_NF_CT_NETLINK_HELPER=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK_GLUE_CT=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_NEEDED=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_PROTO_DCCP=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_PROTO_UDPLITE=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_PROTO_SCTP=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_AMANDA=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_FTP=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_IRC=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_SIP=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_TFTP=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_REDIRECT=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_SYNPROXY=y
CONFIG_NF_TABLES=y
CONFIG_NF_TABLES_INET=y
CONFIG_NF_TABLES_NETDEV=y
CONFIG_NFT_EXTHDR=y
CONFIG_NFT_META=y
CONFIG_NFT_NUMGEN=y
CONFIG_NFT_CT=y
CONFIG_NFT_SET_RBTREE=y
CONFIG_NFT_SET_HASH=y
CONFIG_NFT_COUNTER=y
CONFIG_NFT_LOG=y
CONFIG_NFT_LIMIT=y
CONFIG_NFT_MASQ=y
CONFIG_NFT_REDIR=y
CONFIG_NFT_NAT=y
CONFIG_NFT_QUEUE=y
CONFIG_NFT_QUOTA=y
CONFIG_NFT_REJECT=y
CONFIG_NFT_REJECT_INET=y
CONFIG_NFT_COMPAT=y
CONFIG_NFT_HASH=y
CONFIG_NF_DUP_NETDEV=y
CONFIG_NFT_DUP_NETDEV=y
CONFIG_NFT_FWD_NETDEV=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XTABLES=y

#
# Xtables combined modules
#
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MARK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_CONNMARK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_SET=y

#
# Xtables targets
#
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_AUDIT=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_CHECKSUM=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_CLASSIFY=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_CONNMARK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_CONNSECMARK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_CT=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_DSCP=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_HL=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_HMARK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_IDLETIMER=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_LED=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_LOG=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_MARK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_NAT=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_NETMAP=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_NFLOG=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_NFQUEUE=y
# CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_NOTRACK is not set
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_RATEEST=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_REDIRECT=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_TEE=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_TPROXY=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_TRACE=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_SECMARK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_TCPMSS=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_TCPOPTSTRIP=y

#
# Xtables matches
#
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_ADDRTYPE=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_BPF=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CGROUP=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CLUSTER=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_COMMENT=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNBYTES=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNLABEL=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNLIMIT=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNMARK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNTRACK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CPU=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_DCCP=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_DEVGROUP=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_DSCP=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_ECN=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_ESP=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_HASHLIMIT=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_HELPER=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_HL=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_IPCOMP=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_IPRANGE=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_IPVS=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_L2TP=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_LENGTH=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_LIMIT=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_MAC=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_MARK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_MULTIPORT=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_NFACCT=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_OSF=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_OWNER=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_POLICY=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_PHYSDEV=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_PKTTYPE=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_QUOTA=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_RATEEST=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_REALM=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_RECENT=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_SCTP=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_SOCKET=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_STATE=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_STATISTIC=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_STRING=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_TCPMSS=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_TIME=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_U32=y
CONFIG_IP_SET=y
CONFIG_IP_SET_MAX=256
CONFIG_IP_SET_BITMAP_IP=y
CONFIG_IP_SET_BITMAP_IPMAC=y
CONFIG_IP_SET_BITMAP_PORT=y
CONFIG_IP_SET_HASH_IP=y
CONFIG_IP_SET_HASH_IPMARK=y
CONFIG_IP_SET_HASH_IPPORT=y
CONFIG_IP_SET_HASH_IPPORTIP=y
CONFIG_IP_SET_HASH_IPPORTNET=y
CONFIG_IP_SET_HASH_MAC=y
CONFIG_IP_SET_HASH_NETPORTNET=y
CONFIG_IP_SET_HASH_NET=y
CONFIG_IP_SET_HASH_NETNET=y
CONFIG_IP_SET_HASH_NETPORT=y
CONFIG_IP_SET_HASH_NETIFACE=y
CONFIG_IP_SET_LIST_SET=y
CONFIG_IP_VS=y
CONFIG_IP_VS_IPV6=y
# CONFIG_IP_VS_DEBUG is not set
CONFIG_IP_VS_TAB_BITS=12

#
# IPVS transport protocol load balancing support
#
CONFIG_IP_VS_PROTO_TCP=y
CONFIG_IP_VS_PROTO_UDP=y
CONFIG_IP_VS_PROTO_AH_ESP=y
CONFIG_IP_VS_PROTO_ESP=y
CONFIG_IP_VS_PROTO_AH=y
CONFIG_IP_VS_PROTO_SCTP=y

#
# IPVS scheduler
#
CONFIG_IP_VS_RR=y
CONFIG_IP_VS_WRR=y
CONFIG_IP_VS_LC=y
CONFIG_IP_VS_WLC=y
CONFIG_IP_VS_FO=y
CONFIG_IP_VS_OVF=y
CONFIG_IP_VS_LBLC=y
CONFIG_IP_VS_LBLCR=y
CONFIG_IP_VS_DH=y
CONFIG_IP_VS_SH=y
CONFIG_IP_VS_SED=y
CONFIG_IP_VS_NQ=y

#
# IPVS SH scheduler
#
CONFIG_IP_VS_SH_TAB_BITS=8

#
# IPVS application helper
#
CONFIG_IP_VS_FTP=y
CONFIG_IP_VS_NFCT=y
CONFIG_IP_VS_PE_SIP=y

#
# IP: Netfilter Configuration
#
CONFIG_NF_DEFRAG_IPV4=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_IPV4=y
CONFIG_NF_TABLES_IPV4=y
CONFIG_NFT_CHAIN_ROUTE_IPV4=y
CONFIG_NFT_REJECT_IPV4=y
CONFIG_NFT_DUP_IPV4=y
CONFIG_NF_TABLES_ARP=y
CONFIG_NF_DUP_IPV4=y
CONFIG_NF_LOG_ARP=y
CONFIG_NF_LOG_IPV4=y
CONFIG_NF_REJECT_IPV4=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_IPV4=y
CONFIG_NFT_CHAIN_NAT_IPV4=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_MASQUERADE_IPV4=y
CONFIG_NFT_MASQ_IPV4=y
CONFIG_NFT_REDIR_IPV4=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_SNMP_BASIC=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_PROTO_GRE=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_PPTP=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_H323=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_IPTABLES=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_AH=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_ECN=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_RPFILTER=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_TTL=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_FILTER=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_REJECT=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_SYNPROXY=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_NAT=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_MASQUERADE=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_NETMAP=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_REDIRECT=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_MANGLE=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_CLUSTERIP=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_ECN=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_TTL=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_RAW=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_SECURITY=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_ARPTABLES=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_ARPFILTER=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_ARP_MANGLE=y

#
# IPv6: Netfilter Configuration
#
CONFIG_NF_DEFRAG_IPV6=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_IPV6=y
CONFIG_NF_TABLES_IPV6=y
CONFIG_NFT_CHAIN_ROUTE_IPV6=y
CONFIG_NFT_REJECT_IPV6=y
CONFIG_NFT_DUP_IPV6=y
CONFIG_NF_DUP_IPV6=y
CONFIG_NF_REJECT_IPV6=y
CONFIG_NF_LOG_IPV6=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_IPV6=y
CONFIG_NFT_CHAIN_NAT_IPV6=y
CONFIG_NF_NAT_MASQUERADE_IPV6=y
CONFIG_NFT_MASQ_IPV6=y
CONFIG_NFT_REDIR_IPV6=y
CONFIG_IP6_NF_IPTABLES=y
CONFIG_IP6_NF_MATCH_AH=y
CONFIG_IP6_NF_MATCH_EUI64=y
CONFIG_IP6_NF_MATCH_FRAG=y
CONFIG_IP6_NF_MATCH_OPTS=y
CONFIG_IP6_NF_MATCH_HL=y
CONFIG_IP6_NF_MATCH_IPV6HEADER=y
CONFIG_IP6_NF_MATCH_MH=y
CONFIG_IP6_NF_MATCH_RPFILTER=y
CONFIG_IP6_NF_MATCH_RT=y
CONFIG_IP6_NF_TARGET_HL=y
CONFIG_IP6_NF_FILTER=y
CONFIG_IP6_NF_TARGET_REJECT=y
CONFIG_IP6_NF_TARGET_SYNPROXY=y
CONFIG_IP6_NF_MANGLE=y
CONFIG_IP6_NF_RAW=y
CONFIG_IP6_NF_SECURITY=y
CONFIG_IP6_NF_NAT=y
CONFIG_IP6_NF_TARGET_MASQUERADE=y
CONFIG_IP6_NF_TARGET_NPT=y

#
# DECnet: Netfilter Configuration
#
CONFIG_DECNET_NF_GRABULATOR=y
CONFIG_NF_TABLES_BRIDGE=y
CONFIG_NFT_BRIDGE_META=y
CONFIG_NFT_BRIDGE_REJECT=y
CONFIG_NF_LOG_BRIDGE=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_NF_EBTABLES=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_BROUTE=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_T_FILTER=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_T_NAT=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_802_3=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_AMONG=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_ARP=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_IP=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_IP6=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_LIMIT=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_MARK=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_PKTTYPE=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_STP=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_VLAN=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_ARPREPLY=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_DNAT=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_MARK_T=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_REDIRECT=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_SNAT=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_LOG=y
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_NFLOG=y
CONFIG_IP_DCCP=y
CONFIG_INET_DCCP_DIAG=y
```